# Get Date part Using LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have four tables, with `Date` data type for the fields `startingDate`, `EndingDate`, and `ApplyingDate`.
I am using ADO.net Entity Framework.

I have written the following query to get the results, but I am getting the dates with the time, and I want only the date part.
I have used `EntityFunctions.TuncateTime`, but I am still getting same results.

Could anyone please suggest me, how to Get the date only ?

```
var leaveList = (from application in db.tbl_ApplicationData
     join employee in db.tbl_EmployeeDetails
     on application.UserName equals employee.UserName
     join leaveType in db.tbl_LeaveType
     on application.LeaveTypeId equals leaveType.LeaveTypeId
     join status in db.tbl_Status
     on application.ApplicationStatusId equals status.StatusId
     where application.UserName == "100083"
     select new
     {
         EmployeeName = employee.EmployeeName,
         LeaveTypeID = leaveType.LeaveTypeName,
         StartingDate = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(application.StartingDate),
         EndingDate =  EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(application.EndingDate),
         AppliedDate = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(application.ApplyingDate),
         NoOfDays = application.NoOfDays,
         LeavePurpose = application.LeavePurpose,
         LeaveStatus = status.StatusName
     });
```

Comment: What are the actual results that you are getting back? What is the table's definition? .NET doesn't have a `Date` type so SQL Server `date` columns are mapped to `System.DateTime` values with `00:00:00` time. Calling `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` isn't necessary because a `date` field doesn't have a time part to truncate. If you need to call `TruncateTime` it means that you don't really have `date` columns but one of the other datetime types, eg `datetime` or `datetime2`

Answer (score 2):

If your entity model is a `System.DateTime`, you can just use the `DateTime` methods when you are using your object:

```
select new {
    EndingDate =  application.EndingDate
};

var myValue = leaveList.EndingDate.Date;
```

Or if you want a string:

```
leaveList.EndingDate.ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I have tried your suggestion. It is giving the following error.  The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: Of course ! I forgot about that. I changed my answer.